# Why are all pricing tiers disabled when trying to create a QnA Maker service?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I'm trying to create a QnAMaker service, the second one in my azure tenant. But when doing so I can't select any pricing tier because both are disabled stating that they are not available in the current location, which is weird because I try in the same location of the first QnAMaker service and also in different locations and still get the same issue.

Tried on Safari, Chrome and Edge, same results. Also tried with my personal Azure tenant. :(
I can create other resources but not QnA Maker.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, are you talking about management pricing tier or search pricing tier? As this mainly affected the selected subscription, I would assume that your subscription is somehow the root cause. What kind of subscription are you using? pay as you go? visual studio ?

Comment: Management tiers. I have a pay as you go subscription. And was able to create the first QnAMaker service just fine.

Comment: No credit card provided so far, right? The first one can be created because of a free tier but there can only be one per tenant. Try deleting that instance and add again and you‘ll see the behavior. Add payments method and you should see the options again. The second one will definitely cost you money. If ok, i‘ll add this as an answer.

Comment: Why would I be able to create one payed service but not two? The Subscription has been billed for other services already, the payment methods are managed by the tenant admin.

Comment: so you‘re saying that the first one you created was already on a paid tier and not on free tier? Are you sure its a pay as you go subscription and your administrator did not enforce any limitations, like spending limits?

Comment: No, the first one is in the free tier but I did have the option of the paid one. In fact I just went ahead and moved that one to the paid tier successfully. Then when I try to create a second QnAMaker service I have the same issue, both tiers disabled.

Comment: Actually I just realized the tiers say they are not available in the current location. But I don't understand why, I tried the same location as the first service and also a different one. (South Central US and West US)

Comment: Okay, I still bet on limits on your subscriptions. Do you have the chance to check with your subscription admin?

Comment: I'm working on checking that. Will post back. Thanks

Comment: @BenAffleckIsBatman What limits would we be talking about? On the payment method? Or in the subscription itself? Because I'm owner of the subscription and see no restriction whatsoever

Comment: Forget about the spending limits. This option is not available for pay as you go subscriptions. I created one my self and can provision QnA Maker without a problem, even the second one. I tried different region combinations but could not make it fail. Again, I believe it has to do with the subscription you're working on. Do you have another one you can try? I would consult your tenant admin and let him try to do it. He might not be enforced by some implicit limitations. I'm sorry I have not a better answer...

Comment: Hi again - I experienced this issue myself today! It must be an issue on Microsoft side. Have you raised a ticket already? Otherwise I check back later and open a ticket through the portal. See https://i.imgur.com/zjWyGJU.png for a screenshot. Same situation for you, right?

Comment: I checked back (after 3 hours) and now the issue is gone again. Could you also check back on your side? thanks

Comment: That's exactly the issue. The day I posted this question I was able to create a new one later during the day. But whenI tried to create a second one I wasn't able. Didn't create a ticket for it. I still see the issue right now

Comment: Hi Martin - I was going to open a ticket but then the reply from Ali popped in. I think you can solve your issue with his workaround. If not, I would recommend opening a ticket your-self or wait till the fix it. Hope I was of help. cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same problem, so I got in touch with Microsoft Azure Support and they confirmed the issue originated on their side due to an update to the Azure Portal which caused this problem for some users temporarily.

They suggested for the current time to clear the browser cache + sockets and wait for the TTL to expire, use another browser, or use a completely different system and then login to the Azure Portal again.

The problem got resolved for me using Internet Explorer without waiting for the TTL to expire and using Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome after the TTL has expired.

Comment: Great - I was going to open a ticket myself but couldn't repro it anymore.

Comment: This solution also applies if you created the first QnA service for free?
I see in the comments of the question that you can only create a free service once per subscription, does somebody know if this is true?

Comment: @JuanP.Ortiz I guess you're referring to the `Knowledge Bases` if so you can check the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/limits#knowledge-bases)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the issue - I solved by opening the browser incognito.